# MTW's Gravitation, Box 11.2, etc.: Relative acceleration depends only on $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ at the fiducial point?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, vector-fields

My question relates to MTW's Gravitation, Box 11.2 (copied below) and the discussion on page 271.  This is my paraphrase of the gist of box 11.2:

Consider a family $\Lambda$ of timelike geodesics affinely parameterized
by $\lambda$ and selected by the parameter $n$. The fiducial geodesic
is designated by the selector value $n$. The set of ordered pairs $\left\langle \lambda+\Delta\lambda,n+\Delta n\right\rangle $ may serve as coordinates near $\mathscr{M}.$ In these coordinates,
$\mathscr{M}$ has coordinates $\left\langle \lambda,n\right\rangle $.
Define the vectors $\mathbf{u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}$
and $\mathbf{n}=\frac{\partial}{\partial n}$. The separation between
the fiducial point $\left\langle \lambda,n\right\rangle $ and the
point with the same $\lambda$ value on the geodesic designated by
$n+\Delta n$ is $\vec{n}=\Delta n\mathbf{n}$. The separation $\vec{n}$
is then parallel transported along the geodesic $n$ by $\Delta\lambda,$
so that the tail of its image is at $\mathscr{N}$ and the tip is
at $\mathscr{B}$. A similar image is produced by parallel transport
of $\vec{n}$ along the geodesic $n$ by $-\Delta\lambda,$ with tail
and tip designated $\mathscr{L}$ and $\mathscr{A}$ respectively.

Beginning at the point $\mathscr{Q}$ which has coordinates $\left\langle \lambda,n+\Delta n\right\rangle$
the point $\mathscr{R}$ is determined by a parameter change $\Delta\lambda$
along the geodesic $n+\Delta n.$ The point $\mathscr{P}$ is determined
by a change $-\Delta\lambda$ along the same $n+\Delta n$ geodesic.

The points $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ are determined by parallel
transporting $\vec{n}=\Delta n\mathbf{n}$ along the geodesic $n$
by $-\Delta\lambda$ and $\Delta\lambda$ respectively. The vectors
$\mathscr{B}\mathscr{R}$ and $\mathscr{A}\mathscr{P}$ are then parallel
transported (along unspecified routs) to $\mathscr{Q}$ were they
are summed to produce 
$$
\delta_{2}=\mathscr{B}\mathscr{R}+\mathscr{A}\mathscr{P}=\left(\Delta\lambda\right)^{2}\Delta n\left(\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{n}\right),
$$

where $\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{n}$ is defined
to be the *relative-acceleration vector*.

On page 271 we find:

> [Examine Box 11.4] Thereby arrive at the remarkable equation (11.6)
>
> $$
> \nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{n}+\left[\nabla_{\mathbf{n}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\right]\mathbf{u}=0.
> $$
>
> This equation is remarkable, because at first sight it seems crazy.
>   The term $\left[\nabla_{\mathbf{n}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\right]\mathbf{u}$
>   involves second derivatives of $\mathbf{u}$ and first derivatives
>   of $\nabla_{\mathbf{n}}:$
>
> $$
> \left[\nabla_{\mathbf{n}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\right]\mathbf{u}=\nabla_{\mathbf{n}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{u}-\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\nabla_{\mathbf{n}}\mathbf{u}.
> $$
>
> It thus must depend on how $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$vary from
>   point to point. But the relative acceleration it produces, $\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{n},$
>   is known to depend only on the values of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$
>   at the fiducial point, not on how $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$
>   vary (see box 11.2 F).

I do not understand what this means. The relative acceleration is
derived by multiple parallel transport steps, and taking differences
of vectors at different locations. That is, its establishment involves
more than simply the values of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ at
one point. Therefore, if we interpret "the fiducial point" to
mean, $\mathscr{Q}$ alone, the statement doesn't make sense to me,
at all.

Even if we allow "the fiducial point" to mean any arbitrary point
on the fiducial geodesic, the derivation still involves points not
on that geodesic, and not determined solely by parallel transport
along the fiducial geodesic.

What does it mean to say "$\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{n},$
is known to depend only on the values of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$
at the fiducial point, not on how $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$
vary"?

PS: I believe the essential conclusion is that relative acceleration can be expressed as the operation of a multilinear form (tensor field $\mathbf{\text{Riemann}}$) on $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$.  What I'm not getting is the reasoning leading to that conclusion.

The situation seems similar to that of the differential of a multivariable mapping being a linear mapping associated with its derivative matrix.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just means it's linear in u and n.

Edit

Your relative acceleration vector is just geodesic deviation. It is the physical manifestation of 
the riemann tensor
 R(u, n)u which is a vactor valued 2-form. It tells you the deviation of a geodesic in the neighborhood of n connected by u, at each point p(t) where t is the affine parameter corresponding to the proper time. Iff the rieamann tensor is nonzero inertial geodesics will accelerate with respect to each other (tidal effect). 
So you just want the deviation at a given point, not the deviation of the deviation. That's why the tensor contains no derivatives of u and n. So R(lu, n) u =lR(u, n) u where l is a scalar function.

Comment: That's the short answer.  I guess I am supposed to understand that the multilinear mapping itself is determined by "how $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ vary from point to point", but the value of the mapping does not.  If this is the intent of the authors, I must protest that they do not explain themselves well.  If their intent was to get me study the discussion carefully,  they certainly accomplished that.

Comment: A vector field can vary from point to point. But it is the same vector field.

Comment: I love the style of this book. But the worst thing about it is the very goal the authors had, to show of all the different notations and formalism can complement each other in calculations and conceptual understanding. While such an assumption holds some validity it does fail here because you first need to really understand one way really well but the book keeps skipping from one to another casually.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the relative acceleration vector is the result of a 3-covariant, 1-contravariant tensor operating twice on $\mathbf{u}$, and once on $\mathbf{n}$.  Where $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ are the values at $\mathscr{M}$.  The tensor itself is dependent on how these (or equivalent) field vectors change from point to point.  The individual components of the tensor **do** depend on how the vectors vary from point to point.  That, to me, is no more or less "crazy" than making the same observation about the "tidal forces" term.

Comment: I told you what it means that it doesn't depend on how the fields vary. A covariant derivative with respect to the vector field n does not depend on how n varies. It contains no derivatives of n. Same for the riemann tensor. It can be proven in 3 lines for each slot using some algebra.don't think you can get it from a picture

Comment: But $\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{n}$ does depend on how $\mathbf{n}$ varies from point to point.  In fact it is the quantification of that value.  I guess one might treat the Riemann tensor as existing prior to any coordinate system, and therefore independent of any artifiacts placed on the manifold.   That is, it determines how things vary near an event.  The only value upon which the tensor depends is position.

Comment: No not like that. I meant the covariant derivative in of u with respect to n ( in the direction n) at a point p only depend on the magnitude and direction of n at p.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I finally figured this out.  If we think in terms of a covariantly constant tangent plane moved around the point of evaluation $\mathscr{P}_0$ (I think this is what Cartan called a mobile frame), the second covariant derivative can be thought of as the difference between first covariant derivatives at $\mathscr{P}_\lambda$ and $\mathscr{P}_0$ divided by $\lambda,$ the transport path increment in the limit $\lambda\to{0}$.  In that interpretation, $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ are the coordinate induced basis vectors of the tangent plane, which are non-constant fields.  In Box 11.2 everything is done with respect to a single, fixed tangent plane.  The basis vectors are parallel transported individually, rather than as a coordinate frame.

It seems worth observing that we only take the difference between $\mathbf{n}_\parallel$ and $\mathbf{n}_{\pm\Delta\lambda}$  We never explicitly take the covariant derivative of $\mathbf{u}$ since it is a universal covariant constant.